# Combining two clauses in Neo4j makes query terribly slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm newbie in Neo4j, probably doing something stupid, please, help.

I have 18 mln nodes, each having 2 **string** properties (oid and name). Name is not used in query.

Nodes have relations with one **double** property (val).

When I search for shortest path(s) with filtering on **val** value I get result in milliseconds.

```
MATCH path=shortestPath( (p:ids{oid:'1027700070518'})-[*0..200]-(t:ids{oid:'1027739134950'})) WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.val > 50.0) return length(path) as len, path
```

When I search for shortest path(s) with filtering on **oid** value I also get result in milliseconds.

```
MATCH path=shortestPath( (p:ids{oid:'1027700070518'})-[*0..200]-(t:ids{oid:'1027739134950'})) WHERE NONE(n IN nodes(path) WHERE (n.oid = '1' or n.oid = '2' or n.oid = '3' or n.oid = '4' or n.oid='5' or n.oid = '6' )  ) return length(path) as len, path
```

But combining them to one query makes it run forever.

```
MATCH path=shortestPath( (p:ids{oid:'1027700070518'})-[*0..200]-(t:ids{oid:'1027739134950'})) WHERE ( NONE(n IN nodes(path) WHERE (n.oid = '1' or n.oid = '2' or n.oid = '3' or n.oid = '4' or n.oid='5' or n.oid = '6' )) and (ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.val > 50.0))) return length(path) as len, path
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EXPLAIN doesn't help me, I've made a screenshot.
PROFILE also runs forever.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' is shortestpath(()-[*0..200]-()). Add a case to your graph where a valid path exists in 3 hops and it should run fairly fast... but you set the worst acceptable case as 200 hops on any edge. So assuming that every node (on average) has only 3 edges, and shortestpath won't backtrack on an edge, for all 200 nodes, it has to check 2 hops. Assuming your data is large enough that all of these hops are un-visited, that is 2^200 paths that have to be checked to verify that no path exists (or ^<#_of_allowed_hops>). As you can see, in the worst case, it grows quite quite quickly. You can limit this by reducing the allowed edges (by enforcing direction/type) or limiting hops (if you know that there should be no valid paths longer than 42, go ahead and set that upper bound as low as you can).

In short, when a solution is not easily found, all the possibilities have to be checked) (go ahead and try one of your "good" queries when no valid path exists)

Comment: You are wrong. What impressed me hugely in Neo4j - is the speed of shortestpath/allshortestpaths. I've run tests for 10k random objects from total of 18m and not a single request was slower than 50-100ms. It frequently was 30 or even 52 hops. Answers without path were also blazing fast.

Comment: By the way, I've invented two workarounds for my problem. First is to mark relations of these nodes (number 1-6), so I can live with one filter. Another way is vice versa - to create separate collections for relations of different range and then live only with second filter. First way is almost not ugly. :) But of course, if someone can suggest the right way - I'll gladly accept your help (will start bounty tomorrow)

Comment: @OlegGritsak (1) Cypher is a descriptive language. Just because 2 queries are semantically the same, does not mean Cypher will process them the same. (2) Finding a shortestpath is not finding all paths and filtering down, but about finding one path and ruling out all others. If shortestpath can quickly find a valid path, or rule out that any exist, the performance will be great. What I'm saying, is that under worst case scenarios, the performance has the potential to be catastrophic. (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/)